# How to take printed output of a function and put it in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe, urllib

I have a function that extracts a line of text from a website and adds that text to `url` recursively. My problem is while it prints out the desired output, I want to put that output into a pandas DataFrame where I can clean up the data and do some analysis.

Here is my code so far:

```
from urllib import request

def get_chunk(chunk, url='https://www.uchicago.computer/api.php?file='):
    with request.urlopen(url + chunk) as f:
        return f.read().decode('UTF-8').strip()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    chunk = 'insertsixtyfourrandomcharactershereabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvyxyz123'
    while chunk[-3:] != "END":
        chunk = get_chunk(chunk[-64:])
        print(chunk)
```

The output is printed as so:

```
{"Last Name": "DOE", "First Name": "JOHN", "Job Title": "EXEC SECRETARY/OFFICE MGR", "2020 Annual Salary": "100,000.00"}
RTBFRequest: John Doe
{"Last Name": "JANE", "First Name": "MARY", "Job Title": "CHIEF OF STAFF", "2020 Annual Salary": "11,111.11"}
....
```

But I want to return the output into a dataframe like this where each line of output is its own row.

```
|Entry                  |         
|-----------------------|
|"Last Name": "DOE"...  |
|"RTBFRequest: John"... |
|"Last Name": "JANE"... |
|....                   |
```

I have tried defining an empty list, appending `chunk` to that list, and returning that list so that I could add the output to a DataFrame but it would only return a very small portion of the output.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: how about `df = pd.DataFrame({'Entry':chunk})`?

Comment: I have also tried this. Only returns a small portion of the output

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data = [{"Last Name": "DOE", "First Name": "JOHN", "Job Title": "EXEC SECRETARY/OFFICE MGR", "2020 Annual Salary": "100,000.00"}, {"Last Name": "JANE", "First Name": "MARY", "Job Title": "CHIEF OF STAFF", "2020 Annual Salary": "11,111.11"}]
df = pd.Series(np.array(data)).to_frame('Entry')
```

> Result

```
                                               Entry
0  {'Last Name': 'DOE', 'First Name': 'JOHN', 'Jo...
1  {'Last Name': 'JANE', 'First Name': 'MARY', 'J...
```

Comment: I get the error message: `Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional`